# Inserting python variables into gdal_calc expression?

Tags: python, gdal, gdal-calc

Is it possible to insert a python variable into gdal_calc expression?

For example:

```
mean = [stats[2]] ##mean value
gdal_calc.py -A Input.tif --outfile=Output.tif --calc="1*(A>=mean)" --NoDataValue=0 --type='Byte'
```

Comment: Not tested but maybe something like: `--calc="1*(A>={value})".format(value = mean)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure thing. Since gdal_calc is a python module, you could even import it directly and use as any other module, but it's not really built with that in mind, it's easier to just use it as an utility.

To call a process from terminal/cmd within python, use **os.system**:

```
import os

gdal_path = 'whatever/path/gdal/is/installed/at'
gdal_calc_path = os.path.join(gdal_path, 'gdal_calc.py')

# Arguements.
input_file_path = 'input/file/path/file.tif'
output_file_path = 'output/file/path/file.tif'
calc_expr = '"1 * (A >= mean)"'
nodata = '0'
typeof = '"Byte"'

# Generate string of process.
gdal_calc_str = 'python {0} -A {1} --outfile={2} --calc={3} --NoDataValue={4} --type={5}'
gdal_calc_process = gdal_calc_str.format(gdal_calc_path, input_file_path, 
    output_file_path, calc_expr, nodata, typeof)

# Call process.
os.system(gdal_calc_process)
```

Comment: note: for new python code, you should use the `subprocess` module, not `os.system`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module so it would be `subprocess.run(gdal_calc_process, shell=True)`

Comment: @roberto-ribeiro
Hi, can you please explain the term nodata = '0', i.e., why an integer value needs to be quoted?

I'm experimenting with it but this seems to have no effect on my output, perhaps I'm missing something. 

Thank you

Comment: @PDash It's because you are constructing a string there, which is what os.system uses to run a process. If it's not working, you can construct the gdal_calc call by hand at a text file and try calling it directly from cmd/terminal so you can inspect the error messages.